# ADAL with .NET Core, AWS Lambda and CRM 2016 (on-prem with IFD)

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, lambda, adal

I currently have an AWS Lambda function that connects to the CRM REST API and does a simple select statement and gets the data in a JSON format.  The current CRM install is using SSO with AD authentication.  With this current setup, I have no issues authenticating and requesting data from .NET Core, passing in AD credentials and using the HttpClient to make the request.

We're moving to using CRM with ADFS 3.0 on Windows 2012 R2 to configure IFD. I created the ADFS client using this Powershell command

```
Add-AdfsClient -Name "NAME" -ClientId "11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111" -RedirectUri "https://site.url.com/CRM/" -Description "OAuth 2.0 client CRM"
```

The following code works in .NET 4.5 (or 4.7).

```
string resource = "https://site.url.com/";
string clientId = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111";
string redirectUrl = "https://site.url.com/CRM/";

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/oauth2", false);

AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl), PromptBehavior.Never);
```

With this code, I am able to obtain a token that I can use to put in the HttpClient header using the user who is currently logged into Windows.

My problem comes with I try to do this in .NET Core. I have 2 issues:

1) When running from AWS Lambda, I need some way to pass user credentials.  From what I can tell, AcquireTokenAsync doesn't allow you to pass in a resource, clientId, redirectURL and user credentials.

2) When I run the following code, I get

```
string resource = "https://site.url.com/";
string clientId = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111";
string redirectUrl = "https://site.url.com/CRM/";

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/oauth2", false);

var platformParams = new PlatformParameters();

var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl), platformParams);
```

It will give me this error.  It looks like it's trying to create that dialog, but as one would expect we can't have this dialog come up and I need to be able to pass in the username/password while passing in the redirect url (or CRM OAuth2 will fail).

```
InnerException  {System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WebUIFactory.CreateAuthenticationDialog(IPlatformParameters parameters)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at CRMTestCore.Program.<TestNewTokenWay>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\CRMTestCore\CRMTestCore\CRMTestCore\Program.cs:line 143}  System.Exception {System.NotImplementedException}
```

How can I keep the same AcquireTokenAsync while passing in a username/password that will be used to acquire that token so that it doesn't try to create a prompt?

I am running 3.17.0 of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.

Comment: did you get any success? I am facing same issue.